# Efficient looped search in python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, full-text-search, nltk

I'm trying to perform a search that an address contains references to a country or a city. This would be where the address contains either the full country name, the ISO 2 country code, the ISO 3 country code, or a reference to a city.

Therefore first I generate combinations of the country codes/names/cities (variable "combinations" below) in combination with various items of punctuation, as the addresses are a free text field, the names aren't very clean.

Then for each address I loop through the combinations of and check if the combination is in the address, else return false if no combination is found. However, the is extremely slow with thousands of addresses and country combinations.

The dataset being searched for is all of the table from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1 plus a long list of cities.

And the data being searched includes hundreds of strings like: "Steve; Studio 103, The Business Centre; 61 Wellfield Road; Cardiff; GB"

Is there a way to make this more efficient??

## Find all available combinations of punctuation and country codes

```
def country_code_patterns(country_codes):

    punct1 = [' ',',','/','','']
    punct2 = [' ',',','/','\\','']

    combinations = itertools.zip_longest(punct1, itertools.cycle(country_codes), punct2)
    return combinations 

combinations = country_code_patterns(country_codes)
```

## Loop all combinations and find if combination in address

```
for address in addresses:
    for combination in combinations:
       if combination in address:
          return True
    else:
       return False
```

Comment: Can you add small sample input data sets and your desired data set to your question?

Comment: I don't understand, why you have to create all combinations with punctuations. Wouldn't a regex search be the better strategy?

Comment: Don't think this has to do with `nltk` =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: After understanding the problem a bit better, as you are search for city name and country code pairs you can create a dictionary to hold city names under country code keys.

If you then search for country codes and then only search through cities belonging to that key in the dictionary, you have significantly reduced the number of items in the search. This should be quicker.

-

I would use the itertools library for this, if I have understood correctly what your code is attempting to do I would use izip to concatenate each item from the three lists you are using for a speed boost.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html

Also using list comprehensions will speed up your python code